# When I run npm install and npm start, it keeps coming up with the following messages

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, npm, terminal

namish@namishs-mbp ~ % npm install

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/namish/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/namish/package.json'
npm WARN namish No description
npm WARN namish No repository field.
npm WARN namish No README data
npm WARN namish No license field.

up to date in 0.727s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I'm trying to run `npm start` after this. When I do, this is what happens:

namish@namishs-mbp ~ % npm start

````
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/namish/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/namish/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/namish/.npm/_logs/2020-08-15T01_15_06_560Z-debug.log```

I don't know why this says this. Is there any way to fix it?
````

Comment: It clearly says `npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/namish/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.`

Answer (score 0):

Check the file location of your `package.json` and try again or use `npm init` to create one